# Yii Framework 2.0

Tags: php, database, yii2

I have a database table look like the following:

```
id    item    date
 1    itemA   2014-01-01
 2    itemB   2014-01-01
 3    itemC   2014-02-02
 4    itemD   2014-02-02
```

I would like to retrieve this data and get the result as following.

```
2014-01-01
   itemA
   itemB
2014-02-02
   itemC
   itemD
```

My model class uses Active Record of Yii 2.0. I though about using groupBy('date') as following.

```
$model = MyModelClass::find()->groupBy('date')->all();
```

With above query I get only one row for each date. Is there any solution to approach my goal above within Yii Framework 2.0?

Comment: im unsure what you're trying to get, cant you just loop through the dates and echo when the date changes? ...or use the 'orderBy' function

Comment: that's the idea of `groupBy`, it aggregates the results with the same field you "group by". I'd say you're better off sorting the results by date and then checking the dates on each one before displaying the results

Comment: let's forget about 'group by' because I though it was the solution, but it is not. How can I approach my goal using Active Record within Yii framework 2.0?

Comment: Not really a Yii problem

Answer (score 0):

I would so something like this:

```
$models = MyModelClass::find()->all();
foreach($models as $model) {
    $arr_models[$model->date] = $model;
    //or $arr_models[$model->date][] = $model->name; to get the array exactly how you want it
}
```

If you have a lot of records that you need to go through you can always use `MyModelClass::find()->asArray()->all();`

Answer (score 0):

Hi you  get only one row for each date, because groupBy('date') is used when you want to find the average, or sum or count of numerical values in column item.

a solution is

```
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;

$models = MyModelClass::find()->asArray()->all();

$array = ArrayHelper::map($models, 'id','item','date');
```

you can loop through $array to take the results